# Correct way to handle linking in Makefiles?

Tags: c, linux, dependencies, makefile

I'm currently working on a project in which there are about 20 c source files and about 8 binary targets. We're finding the Makefile upkeep fairly difficult and error prone. The main issue is in recording which binaries depend on which object files, because automatic header dependency resolution seems fairly straightforward (but we haven't yet implemented it).

This is an example of the way our makefile is currently set up. Two programs foo and bar. Foo needs to use functions exported from timestamp.c and bar needs to use functions exported from pretty_print.c which in turn uses timestamp functions to generate time-stamped strings.

```
foo bar:
     $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

foo: foo.o timestamp.o
foo.o: timestamp.h   

bar: bar.o pretty_print.o timestamp.o
bar.o: pretty_print.h 

pretty_print.o: pretty_print.h timestamp.h

timestamp.o: timestamp.h
```

Is there a better way to do this (apart from automatic generation of the foo.o and bar.o lines)? I feel as though there must be a better way than writing that bar depends on timestamp.o when it doesn't include timestamp.h. This is the source of most mistakes actually. It is not until the linker can't find symbol "create_timestamp" that we realise that pretty_print relies on functions from timestamp. Perhaps this is just the way it works?

Comment: A small tip: In the rules for the object file (e.g. the `timestamp.o:` line), you should not only have the header files included in the source, but also the source file. So the rule for `timestamp.o` would look like this: `timestamp.o: timestamp.c timestamp.h`.

Comment: If you don't use an IDE which automatically keeps track of this, or other tools like automake, then you are out of luck and have to manually edit the correct makefiles when you find a new dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linking is still a relatively traditional part of the build process.  Adding another source file is an infrequent and relatively heavyweight (create new source and header files, add to source control, add copyright boilerplate) task, so there hasn't been a lot of pressure to automate the comparatively trivial subtask of adding one more object file to a couple of link recipes.

So in fact I would write this in an even more straightforward way:

```
FOO_OBJS = foo.o timestamp.o
foo: $(FOO_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(FOO_OBJS) $(LIBS)

BAR_OBJS = bar.o pretty_print.o timestamp.o
bar: $(BAR_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(BAR_OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

If you really want to avoid worrying about which binary targets need which miscellaneous object files, you can divide the object files into the canonical ones corresponding to each binary target (`foo.o`, `bar.o`, etc) and miscellaneous others, and put the latter into a miscellaneous linker library:

```
foo: foo.o libmisc.a
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ foo.o libmisc.a $(LIBS)

bar: bar.o libmisc.a
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ bar.o libmisc.a $(LIBS)

MISC_OBJS = pretty_print.o timestamp.o
libmisc.a: $(MISC_OBJS)
    -rm -f $@
    $(AR) rc $@ $(MISC_OBJS)
    -$(RANLIB) $@
```

Then linking each binary target (`foo`, `bar`) will only pull in exactly the miscellaneous object files that it needs.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. A misc library in which to put everything seems like the easy way to go. Would creating a shared library make sense instead of a .a file?

Comment: @Chris - a .a file is a shared library. The objects are archived together into libmisc.a and then the linker only extracts the files that are necessary during linking.

Comment: @Alex: No, a .a file is a **static** library.  Chris is asking about deploying a .so library instead, and as usual the answer is "it depends". If there are a lot of binary targets often all running at once that each use a lot of the miscellaneous object files, then there would be some reduction in total memory used. If the binaries use small disjoint subsets of the miscellaneous objects (unlikely), then it wouldn't be worth it. Unless the binaries are all packaged & installed together, I wouldn't dream of a shared library as you'd be buying into versioning issues for no gain. Otherwise, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this myself, but to list link dependencies you could use [nm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_%28Unix%29) with some simple text postprocessing.

Answer (score -1):

Scripts to automate the generation of the needed lines in makefiles like this already exist.

See "makedepend" or "mkdepend" -- that's how people usually do this in practice. It is common enough that they're shipped with most flavors of Unix.

Comment: makedepend will deduce *header* dependencies (e.g.`bar.o: pretty_print.h`), but not *linking* dependencies (e.g. `bar: timestamp.o`) which is what the OP is asking for.